# Make a math function like a picture below

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I want to type the `math` function as below.

[image]

I try to make it with this code.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \phi: R&\to R\\
        a+b\sqrt{2}&\mapsto a+b
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

I don't know how to align `$phi$` into left side before `$a+b\sqrt{2}$` and align `$R$` in the center of `$a+b\sqrt{2}$` and `$a+b$` (as first picture). How to make it?

Comment: You're welcome @CarLaTeX. Thanks for your help too.

Comment: Is the function well-defined?

Comment: The function is well defined. In that function, $R=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: That was in connection with CarLaTeX's answer where `\mathbb{R}` is suggested (and it shouldn't be). Of course, if *R* denotes the ring of integers with the square root of 2 adjoined, then the function is well defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `array` (and `\colon` instead of `:`):

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{l@{$\;$}c@{$\;$}c@{$\;$}c}
    \phi\colon & R &\to& R\\
    & a+b\sqrt{2}&\mapsto &a+b 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See the comment from the OP: `\mathbb{R}` is definitely not wanted in this case. `;-)`

Comment: @CarLaTeX, the sets $R$ is defined by $R=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ instead of real numbers (\mathbb{R}).

Comment: @egreg Corrected ^^^

Answer (score 2):

The following requires two compilations with any change within the maximum width of every `\eqmakebox[<tag>]` using the same `<tag>`. A second (optional) argument can be specified for aligning the content to the `l`eft or `r`ight (`c`entred is default).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \phi \colon \eqmakebox[ab2]{$      R      $} \to     \eqmakebox[ab]{$  R  $} \\
              \eqmakebox[ab2]{$a + b\sqrt{2}$} \mapsto \eqmakebox[ab]{$a + b$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```